# How to get val() of option in jQuery object array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following `select` tag:

```
<select id="myselect">
    <option value="1">Mr</option>
    <option value="2">Mrs</option>
    <option value="3">Ms</option>
    <option value="4">Dr</option>
    <option value="5">Prof</option>
</select>
```

How can I `console.log` the value of `option` tag number `2`? I am trying this, but it isn't working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log($("#myselect option")[2].val());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u44pu1os/3/

Comment: Try this: `console.log($("#myselect option:selected").val());

Comment: @holpducki The question asks specifically for the value of the second option, not the selected option (whatever that might be).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log($("#myselect option:eq(1)").attr("value"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
console.log($('#myselect option[value="2"]').html());
```